# Google Optimize and AMP integration

Tags: amp-html, google-optimize

I'm trying to run some A/B tests with Optimize on my AMP (Wordpress) Website.
I'm using the official Wordpress AMP Plugin and adding my analytics setup through a hook provided by the plugin. I will show you the final HTML output.

What I've done so far:

1. I've made sure that both amp-experiment and amp-analytics scripts are included in my page(the WordPress plugin includes all the required scripts automatically.)
2. Setup an experiment named testExperiment. Its ID is 51vXPC_HQcCA-kjuWP5XFQ.
3. Potential problem: Optimize diagnostics shows the following errors:
   Analytics tracking code not found
   Optimize plugin not found
   Analytics is 100% integrated, as it shows live views on my website. I suppose that the diagnostics are not working correctly due to the specific AMP integration process.
4. I've created a variant, created targeting rule, linked with analytics,  set up an objective.
5. I've added the following amp-experiment and amp-analytics scripts in my page.​

```
    <amp-experiment>
        <script type="application/json">
            {
                "testExperiment": {
                    "sticky": false,
                    "variants": {
                        "0": 50,
                        "1": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </amp-experiment>
```

​My analytics script output in the source of the page looks like this:

```
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "vars": {
                "account": "UA-54160702-17"
            },
            "requests": {
                "experiment": "${pageview}&xid=${xid}&xvar=${xvar}"
            },
            "triggers": {
                "trackPageview": {
                    "on": "visible",
                    "request": "pageview",
                    "extraUrlParams": []
                },
                "pageview": {
                    "on": "visible",
                    "request": "experiment",
                    "vars": {
                        "xid": "51vXPC_HQcCA-kjuWP5XFQ",
                        "xvar": "VARIANT(testExperiment)"
                    }
                }
            },
            "transport": {
                "beacon": "true",
                "xhrpost": "true",
                "image": "false"
            }
        }
    </script>
```

6. ​I've added the following CSS to my page:

```
    body[amp-x-testExperiment="0"] .clr-expr {
      background-color: #00cebe;
    }

    body[amp-x-testExperiment="1"] .clr-expr {
      background-color: #353c8c;
    }
```

---

The experiment attribute is not added to the body of the page and I'm seeing the following errors in the console:

[image]

The page I'm trying to test on is: https://dev.somnishop.com/was-tun-gegen-schnarchen-frauen/

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with the Wordpress AMP plugin.
[This](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-optimize-integration-2/) is the support thread if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with amp-experiment tag version 1.0, so I replaced it with amp-experiment tag version 0.1 and it solves the issues
version 1.0 is not stable so it shouldn't be used yet — https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/21705